# Search results - 404 error after hitting enter

Tags: search

So I am using a theme from envato and there's extremely poor response from the support team and I hate not trying things on my own.

On the website I am working on right now there's a problem with search page and search results.

When going into search and typing, you can clearly see that there are some matches (let's say "sport") but when hitting an enter/search button the page goes straight into 404 error.

I when you perform search on the 404 page, the search is available but the result page goes bollocks!

Any advice on how to work on it without access to search.php (blocked by the owner of the theme)

page address: https://youthtalkedinburgh.co.uk/ 
theme used: Kleo

Answer (score 0):

It appears your search is going to `https://youthtalkedinburgh.co.uk/?post_type[]=&s=sport` instead of the (more proper) `https://youthtalkedinburgh.co.uk/?s=sport`, which works. Looking at the source, it appears your search form looks like this (simplified):

```
<form  ... >
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="">
<input name="s"... >
...
</form>
```

That `<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="">` input field doesn't seem to belong. I suspect either your theme or a plugin is inserting it, but I couldn't begin to guess which one.

You may still have to take this up with the theme's support team (or a plugin's support team), but at least you've got a place to start looking.